# Condition in dimension value

Tags: endeca

Can somebody help me with situation when I need not accurate value in dimension values and some dynamic range values but not predefined? For example if I want get all products with price less then 1000 but more than 700. How to configure this situation in pipeline or with Assembler API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pipeline, you can define a Dimension values of Type: range, so long as you know the range in advance.

In order to retrieve an arbitrary range you can do so with the following query parameter:

```
Nf=p_PRICE|BTWN 0 100 (for a range)
Nf=p_PRICE|LTEQ 100  (for all < 100)
Nf=p_PRICE|GTEQ 100  (for all > 100
```

Good luck